# Win7 VM on top of native Win7, both using OEM SLP key

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, oem

I was wondering if it's possible to install Win7 in VM, using the same OEM SLP key as the native Win7 on which I would like to install it.

Since I do a lot of Windows development and tinkering about, I'd like to have an isolated dev environment that I can restore quickly in case it becomes clogged of broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I've set up a VM. The answer is yes, this will work perfectly.